# How to Simulate native iOS App in different Geographical Locations and perform latency Testing

Tags: ios, mobile, latency

How to perform latency test for native iOS Mobile App by simulating different geographical locations and measure the time taken for each real-time user actions in the Mobile App?

Please recommend any simple techniques

Comment: To simulate latency, look into the network link conditioner https://www.natashatherobot.com/simulate-bad-network-ios-simulator/

Comment: Thanks @AndrewYochum for your suggestion. But my requirement is to test ap launching time(screen loading time) in real device in various geographical locations like UK, AUS and Finland. Just to make sure, if we need to add new aws host for our app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS Device Farm. It allows to you select from a variety of devices in the AWS datacenters. https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This will be first option

Comment: Device Farm will allow you to mock the location on the device however the devices are all located in us-west-2 region. Which mean if you're trying to test for round trip time of network request in the app then this might not work for the use case.